# Proving row reduced form is unique understanding why last row has leading one

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read this proof:
https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Yuster19807.pdf
Why does the have to be a leading one in the last column? Couldn't just one of B or C, say B need to have a leading one without the other having one?

Answer (score 0):

As the proof states, suppose $Bx=0$. This implies (since row operations preserve the solution set) that $Ax=0$, and so $Cx=0$. Then this implies $(B-C)x=0$, and (since the first $n-1$ columns of $B$ and $C$ are the same, and it is assumed that $b_{j,n} \neq c_{j,n}$) this implies $x_n=0$. Therefore, if $Bx=0$ then $x_n=0$, so $B$ must have a leading $1$ in the last column.

You can do the same argument starting with $Cx=0$ (which implies $Ax=0$, and so $Bx=0$) and also derive $x_n=0$. This again implies that $C$ has a leading $1$ in the last column.

Comment: Why does xn being zero mean that both of them have leading ones though as the reason we get xn=0 is because bnj=/=cnj, what about if bnj=1 and cnj=0?

Comment: Oops, I made a typo, those should be $c_{j,n}$ and $b_{j,n}$. In any case, those are not necessarily the leading entries in the last column. They are just *some* entries in the last column where $B$ and $C$ differ. The reason you know there must be a leading $1$ in the last column of $B$ (in the first paragraph in my answer) is because $Bx=0$ implies $x_n=0$. If there were no leading $1$ in the last column of $B$, then $x_n$ would be a free variable, which would contradict the fact that we found $x_n$ *must* be $0$.

Comment: By free variable do you mean that you could construct a set of entries such that xn is not 0?

Comment: @4M4D3U5M0Z4RT I mean for any real number $a$, there is a vector $x$ in the solution set of $Bx=0$ that has $x_n=a$.